# UiPickerView with Images Error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have UiPickerView and colorCode.Plist - which contains names of images.

I need to add these images to my picker View.

---

**UipickerView**

4 component

10 images in first 3 component

4 images in 4th component

---

Programs like Resistor Colour Code for Electrical use. (Error thrown)

```
  {
@interface ResistorsColorView ()
{
NSArray *colorCode;    
}

@end

@implementation ResistorsColorView


- (void)viewDidLoad

{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"colorCode" ofType:@"plist"];
colorCode = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
}

#  pragma mark - Datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
 return colorCode.count;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
return [colorCode[component]count];
}

//- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:    (NSInteger)component{
//
//    return colorCode[component][row];
//}



-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:            (NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{


UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];

imageView.image = colorCode[component][row];

imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[record objectForKey:@"row1"]];




[v addSubview:imageView];

return v;
}

@end
```

Comment: Post the error in your question.

Comment: eption', reason: '-[__NSCFString _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e6e300'

Answer (score 0):

reason: '-[__NSCFString _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e6e300' –